# How to populate dropdownlist with hours in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have to **2 dropdownlists** and I want to populate them with their values as hours from **1 to 24**. Then I want to calculate the difference between the two selected values. If i choose in the first dropdown let's say the hour value as 12 AND second value as 16 then the difference will be 4.

**How can I achieve that in c#?**

I'm developing a asp.net web application coded in **C#**.

**Below is  the code of how I populate my dropdownlist:**

```
 DateTime Date = DateTime.Today;
 DateTime Time = DateTime.Now;
 ListItem item1 = new ListItem(Time.ToShortTimeString(),
                               Time.ToShortTimeString());
         
 for (int i = 0; i <= 48; i++)
 {
   ListItem item2 = new ListItem(Date.ToShortTimeString(), 
                                 Date.ToShortTimeString());
             
   droplist.Items.Add(item2);
                
               
   if (Date.CompareTo(Time) < 0 && Date.AddMinutes(30).CompareTo(Time) > 0)
     droplist.Items.Add(item1);
                    
   Date = Date.AddMinutes(60);
 }
```

**How can I assign values to my dropdown, values being the hours?**

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: Where do you want the difference between the two dropdown values to display?

Comment: I'm a little confused - You state you want 1 to 24, but the code seems to imply you want current hour + 24. Which is it?

Comment: in a label..it doesn't matter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of adding the date/time string to the drop down, you may add the `DateTime` value itself. The dropdown displays its members by calling `ToString()`. The disadvantage here: you are not able to use another time format like `ToShortTimeString()`.

Another way is to use the `DateTime.TryParse` method to convert back before calculating.